# Regex to split string at before, multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, split

I need to be able to split a string with Regex (using VB.net) and:

- Retain the delimiter character in the parts
- Split before the parts.

So far I have:

`Regex.Split(MyString, "(?<=[<@])")`

This is splitting by my two delimiters (@ and <) perfectly, but I am getting the @ or < character in the wrong part, so I need to split one step behind each split we are currently getting...

ie, this < is > a @string

is currently splitting to:

- this <
- is> a @
- string

But I want:

- this
- < is > a
- @string

Any help much appreciated! Regex baffles me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookahead instead of lookbehind for splitting:

```
(?=[<@])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qG4bZ2/1)